# World coverage in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: openlayers-2, shapefile, wms

I gave a demo this afternoon and it couldn't have gone any worse :(

I checked everything was working before I started (apart from the external internet connection)....  My dependency on an external WMS layer of the world coastline causes my app to hang so I would like to serve out my own world coverage rather than rely on any external resource but where do I get the data and the SLD from. I have a shapefile of the world coastline but it doesn't look half as good as the default openlayers basemap.

My base layer is configured like so:

```
//create the basemap
basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
    "Baselayer", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", 
    {layers: 'basic'}, 
    {
        singleTile: true, 
        ratio: 1, 
        isBaseLayer: true
    }
);
```

I would like to be totally independent of external resources (http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org above) and rather serve this data out myself via geoserver (wms).

Comment: If you're working with a shapefile, wouldn't it be better to use WFS over WMS for the data transfer ?

Comment: Debatable!  Seeing as I'm using the data for nothing but a baselayer I don't see any reason to use WFS over WMS!?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, WMS sends an image made from the vector data stored on the server, as WFS sends the data itself, which is interpreted by your GIS... If you're not using that data, it won't make much of a difference, except when zooming (an image will pixelate, while vector data will be redrawn and adjusted, therefore will be less aliased.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for good global low scale data, check [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), load it on your GeoServer and style it.

Comment: That's great thanks, I considered using the openstreetmap planet dataset but this is over 100GB so I think I'll give that a miss!